# Google Sheet Query to pull rows with errors

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to utilize Google Sheet to pull out rows which has errors.

Below is a screenshot on how the raw data looks like (Raw Data 1):
[image]

Column A is the key, which is used in Column F to do a VLOOKUP in another tab. If not found, replace with a "-" string value, as below:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Raw Data 2'!$A:$E,5,FALSE), "-")
```

Column G checks whether Column E = Column F.

Column H is a formula which is (F-E)/E. In this case, a "#VALUE!" error pops out due to column F, which is okay for now.

Below is my processed tab with the formula:
[image]

```
=QUERY('Raw Data 1'!A:J, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J WHERE F='-'")
```

I have also tried:

```
=QUERY('Raw Data 1'!A:J, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J WHERE H='#VALUE!'")
```

Both give me empty results. Is there a way to make the query work such that it picks up rows where the VLOOKUP in Column F fails, or when Column H returns an error?

Edit 1: I am not able to use "Filter" as my Query needs to exclude Column I.

Thanks!

Edit 2: Created a sample sheet for reference thanks to the suggestion of @player0: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Htj6O5VbGyRCB_X7Q0epIg8OkhrHEFYnMAH1HJckVDo/edit#gid=1568356550

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=FILTER('Raw Data 1'!A:J, 'Raw Data 1'!F:F="-")
```

Or:

```
=FILTER('Raw Data 1'!A:J, ISERROR('Raw Data 1'!H:H))
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT('Raw Data 1'!A:J), "WHERE Col6='-'", ))
```

[image]

Comment: oh wow thank you, that works! Do you happen to know why it doesn't work with a query statement instead?

Comment: @lyk most likely (without proper investigatiom) its formatting... query likes to make assumptions what to output. if your dataset has mixed numeric values and text strings then query will decide what to output based on majority (hiding the minority) sometimes query gets so confused what to do, it will output nothing :) like in your case. workaround in such scenarios would be to use `FILTER` or forced formatting like: `=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT('Raw Data 1'!A:J), "where Col6 = '-'", ))` tho the second will render numeric values into text strings

Comment: I edited the main post with a new link that somewhat shows the issue. I had to duplicate it due to data sensitivity reasons. Will also try out the forced formatting solution you proposed!

Comment: @lyk answer updated